# Inequalities involving the sine of Complex Variable z

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any relationship between $|\sin z|$ , $\sin |z|$ , and $|z|$ ??? I know in real variables for example we have that $|\sin x|\le|x|$

Comment: Maybe check here!? http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.18

Answer (score 2):

No.  For complex $z$, it is not true that $|\sin(z)|\leq |z|$ for small $|z|$.  To see this note that
$$\sin (x+i y)=\sin (x) \cosh (y)+i\cos (x) \sinh (y).$$
Setting $x=0$ and taking the absolute value, we get 
$$|\sin (i y)|=|\sinh (y)| > |y|$$
for $y\neq0$.
You can also explore [the graph of $|\sin(iy)|$ as compared to $|y|$](http://goo.gl/zLL8Ha):

[image]

Nonetheless, it is *still* the case that $\sin(z)\approx z$ for small $z$.  This is easily seen from the Taylor expansion of the sine.

Answer (score 0):

Well since $|z|$ is real you certainl have $|sin|z||<|z|$.